# Remove Safari/Chrome iframe glow

Tags: css, webkit

Is there a way to remove the outer glow of an IFrame in Webkit?

I tried this:

```
iframe {outline: none; -moz-outline: 0; border: 1px solid #000; z-index: 1;}
```

But it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you have to define `webkit-appearance:none;` for `webkit` browsers . Like this:

```
iframe{
 webkit-appearance:none;
}
```